# Vue conditional button text based on data variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 3 desks in a table having `role_id` 2, 4 and 6.  I have two tables. I want to display a different role name on a button based on the current user's `role_id`.

I want to display:

- the role name having `role_id` 4 if the current `user_role_id` = 2
- the role name having `role_id` 6 if the current `user_role_id` = 4.

user table
[image]

registration table
[image]

code

```
<span v-if="user.user_role_id ==results.desk_user_role_id">
    <v-btn small color="primary"  v-on:click="getNextDesk" style="width:400px;">Forward to </v-btn>
    <v-btn small color="primary" v-on:click="getPreviousDesk" style="width:400px;">Revert </v-btn>
</span>
```

Script code

```
getNextDesk(currentdeskid) {
  if (currentdeskid === 2) {
    return 'Technical Desk';
  }
  if (currentdeskid === 4) {
    return 'Executive Desk';
  }
  return '';
},
getPreviousDesk(currentdeskid) {
  if (currentdeskid === 6) {
    return 'Technical Desk';
  }
  if (currentdeskid === 4) {
    return 'Registration Desk';
  }
  return '';
},
```

Comment: Are you just trying to change the button name on click?

Comment: Actually I have 3 user for now i.e registration, technical and executive. Registration will forward record to technical. So, when registration login, button with forward to technical should be displayed in home page, when technical login, button with forward to executive should be displayed in home page and so on. @Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my best guess about what you're trying to do:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      user: { user_role_id: 2 },
      roles: {
        2: { name: 'Registration', next: 4 },
        4: { name: 'Technical', next: 6, previous: 2 },
        6: { name: 'Executive', previous: 4 }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    forwardTo() {
      const { next } = this.roles[this.user.user_role_id];
      return next ? 'Forward to ' + this.roles[next].name : false;
    },
    revertTo() {
      const { previous } = this.roles[this.user.user_role_id];
      return previous ? 'Revert to ' + this.roles[previous].name : false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
  User:
  <select v-model="user.user_role_id">
    <option v-for="(role, id) in roles" :value="id">{{ role.name }}</option>
  </select>
  </div><br />
  
  <button v-show="forwardTo">{{ forwardTo }}</button>
  <button v-show="revertTo">{{ revertTo }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try it. Thank  you.  @Dan

Comment: I got 'name' is assigned a value but never used . 'previous' is assigned a value but never used 'name' is assigned a value but never used 'previous' is assigned a value but never used. @Dan

Comment: Those are just lint warnings, not an actual error...  I updated the code anyway.

Comment: I need  to call v-on:click on same button for vue.js axios post method. Can I call both v-show and v-on:click on same button?

Comment: Yes sure, try it out:  `<button v-show="forwardTo" @click="myMethod">`

Comment: It's not working. I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined and Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined"

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question and show the button + method code

Comment: Here is the link. Please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283659/unable-to-call-v-show-and-click-on-same-button-with-vue-js. @Dan

Comment: Can I ask you a question?

Comment: Yes, what's up?

Comment: How to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170706/remote-http-basic-access-denied-fatal-authentication-failed-for-https-gitl @Dan